# Wifi hotspot in NetworkManager not connect after system upgrade

Tags: linux, arch-linux, networkmanager

I have a problem with Hotspot Wifi in NetworkManager.

Everything was working yesterday. The Hotspot has been operating normally for several years.
I made an update of the Antergos system using `sudo pacman -Syu`.

Internet on the computer works normally but Hotspot does not work.
The following message appears: "network connection activation failed".

Here are the latest logs from NetworkManager `journalctl -u NetworkManager`:
https://pastebin.com/xcQT6qJt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://forum.antergos.com/topic/11182/wifi-no-longer-working-on-freshly-installed-antergos-bcm43142/

`downgrade wpa_supplicant` has helped.

But I had yet to install `pacman -S pacman-contrib` because the `downgrade` needed `pacsort`.